# Canvas clipping mask positioning issue

Tags: css, html, canvas, clip

Long story short - take a look at simple fiddle below. Long story - I'm using HTML5 Canvas and SVG path clipping mask to mask out custom shape from image. Everything works as expected, apart from when I try to position container elswhere.

You can see issue in question in this Fiddle right here - https://jsfiddle.net/eyv35f6k/1/

```css
body {
  padding: 0; 
  margin: 0
  }
  
  .container {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    /* *********** top: 50px; *********** */
  }

.css-clipped {
  display: block; 
  -webkit-clip-path:url(#svgPath);
  clip-path:url(#svgPath);
  }
```

```html
<!- Element that cointains image that must be clipped by using custom shape  ->
  <div class="container">
    <img class="css-clipped" src="https://sarasoueidan.com/demos/css-svg-clipping/html-img-clipped-with-css/flowers.jpg">
  </div>


<!- SVG that contains clop path ->
  <svg height="0" width="0">
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="svgPath">
        <path fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.0" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="m49,0c2,0 4,0 6,0c16,1 30,3 36,13c6,9 7,23 7,36c0,13 -1,27 -7,36c-6,10 -20,12 -36,13c-2,0 -4,0 -6,0l0,0c-2,0 -4,0 -6,0c-16,-1 -30,-3 -36,-13c-6,-9 -7,-23 -7,-36c0,-13 1,-27 7,-36c6,-10 20,-12 36,-13c2,0 4,0 6,0l0,0z"/>
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
  </svg>
```

If you will try to move around *.container* element, you will see that container and image inside it moves, while canvas mask remains in the same top left corner of the page body, instead of moving together with element it's been applied to. I made example picture in photoshop to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Could you please advise me, how to make it so that canvas mask moves together with element it's applied to? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use clipping in at least 2 ways:

**Viewport Mode:**

As you drag, clipping reveals a "window" onto different smaller parts of the larger image underneath.

**Drag-a--static-Clip Mode:**

A small static image is clipped from the larger image.  As you drag, the static image is moved around the canvas.

**Here's example code and a Demo showing both clipping modes.**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
function reOffset(){
    var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    offsetX=BB.left;
    offsetY=BB.top;        
}
var offsetX,offsetY;
reOffset();
window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }
window.onresize=function(e){ reOffset(); }

var isDown=false;
var startX,startY;

var ox=0;
var oy=0;
var width=75;
var height=50;
var mode='Viewport'
var clippedImage;

var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://sarasoueidan.com/demos/css-svg-clipping/html-img-clipped-with-css/flowers.jpg";
function start(){
    clipImage=createClipImg(ox,oy,width,height);
    $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
    $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUpOut(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseUpOut(e);});
    //
    $('input[type=radio][name=group1').change(function(){
        mode=this.value;
        if(mode=='Drag'){
            clippedImage=createClipImg(ox,oy,width,height);
        }
        draw();
    });
    draw();
}

function draw(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
    if(mode=='Viewport'){
        clippedViewport(ox,oy,width,height);
    }else{
        ctx.drawImage(clippedImage,ox,oy);
    }
}

function clippedViewport(x,y,w,h){
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(x,y,w,h);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.clip();
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    ctx.restore();
}

function createClipImg(x,y,w,h){
    var c=document.createElement('canvas');
    var cctx=c.getContext('2d');
    c.width=w;
    c.height=h;
    cctx.drawImage(img,-x,-y);
    return(c);
}



function handleMouseDown(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  //
  startX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  startY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
  // Put your mousedown stuff here
  if(startX>ox && startX<ox+width && startY>oy && startY<=oy+height){
      isDown=true;
  }
}

function handleMouseUpOut(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  // Put your mouseup stuff here
  isDown=false;
}

function handleMouseMove(e){
  if(!isDown){return;}
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  //
  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
  // Put your mousemove stuff here
  var dx=mouseX-startX;
  var dy=mouseY-startY;
  startX=mouseX;
  startY=mouseY;
  //
  ox+=dx;
  oy+=dy;
  draw();
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
canvas{border:1px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Mode:&nbsp
<input type=radio name=group1 value=Viewport checked>Viewport
<input type=radio name=group1 value=Drag>Drag clip
<hr>
"Viewport" reveals different part of the image underneath.
<br>
"Drag clip" drags the same clipped image part around the canvas.
<hr>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

**[Addition: Images clipped into html5 canvas]**

You can draw a clipped image onto an html5 canvas (1 canvas per image) and then use the canvas just like you would use an image.

[image][image]

```js
var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://sarasoueidan.com/demos/css-svg-clipping/html-img-clipped-with-css/flowers.jpg";
function start(){
    var container=document.getElementById('container');
    for(var i=0;i<6;i++){
        makeClippedCanvas(img,100,100,container);
    }
}


function makeClippedCanvas(img,w,h,container){
    var c=document.createElement("canvas");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    c.width=w;
    c.height=h;
    //
    ctx.moveTo(50,0);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(100,5, 100,15, 100,50);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(100,85, 100,95, 50,100);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(0,95, 0,85, 0,50);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(0,15, 0,5, 50,0);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.clip();
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    container.appendChild(c);
    return(c);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#container{width:50%; border:1px solid blue;}
canvas{margin:5px;}
```

```html
<h4>Resize the window</h4>
<div id=container></div>
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for answer - although you misunderstood me a bit, the result of "static image" in your example seems to be what's necessery for me. The thing is that I don't actually have to *move* around those containers that has clip mask inside them  - I simply want to have multiple thumbnails in grid view (number of images can differ), and each of them clipped with this mask.

So - can this be achieved without javascript but with pure CSS, as in my original post? - simply multiple elements, arranged in grid view (display inline-block or float), each having clipped image thumbnail inside?

Comment: I updated my post above with screenshot of what I'm trying to achieve, I hope it explains it better.

Comment: I've added to my answer based on your clarification.

Comment: Perfect solution! Thank you very much. Marked as best answer as well!

Comment: Just one more quick question - could you also suggest best way to convert my SVG path to ctx.bezierCurve that you have shown? Because designer was quite specific about the shape of the clipped mask that should be exactly like the one in fiddle I posted at the beginning.

Comment: Sure. I'd highly recommend Mike Swanson's [Adobe Illustrator plugin](http://blog.mikeswanson.com/ai2canvas) that converts SVG into html5 canvas drawing commands. Alternatively, you can fine-tune the curves in my demo -- it wouldn't take too much alteration to exactly reproduce your svg shape. Alternatively, if you need on-the-fly conversions you might check out [canvg](https://github.com/gabelerner/canvg).

Comment: Great information - thank you once again. Highly appreciated.

Comment: If you just need that one svg shape converted to canvas then I've done it for you [here](https://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/Lfc0b72j/).

Comment: Thanks for spearing me half an hour of work. Just implemented it in test enviroment, and works like a charm. :)